# Zalenium hub IP on remote AWS

Tags: docker, zalenium

I am new on Zalenium and Docker. I am learning using a tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9TN5IkyJ030.

I am running steps provided in this tutorial on one remote AWS Linux machine. Which I am able to access via putting. After completing all the steps I am able to see hub and nodes running.

But how to access this remotely setup Zalenium Grid console on my Windows Browser?

It is how it looks

[image]

[image]

Comment: So, you have a container running successfully on aws, but you can't access it via your browser at the Public IP/DNS server that AWS is giving you? Is that the gist of your question?

First, I'd try to curl the service from your remote instance. If you get a response and it's not timing out, then I'd check your security group and make sure that it's accessible from your local network.

Comment: whats that curl command? and how to check that service part? By the way am I hitting the correct <ipaddress>:4444/wd/hub??MY guess is I need to hit same ip address which I have in top left corner (hidden)

Comment: The curl command will send a GET request to the service running in docker. In your remote shell (assuming curl is installed), try `curl localhost:4444` or thereabouts. If an error is not returned then this might not be a docker issue. So, then I would check your security group on AWS to make sure that port 4444 is accessible from your local network.

Comment: I checked `curl localhost:4444` didnt give any error. How to check the next part?

Comment: Look through amazon's documentation on this issue:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#adding-security-group-rule

By default port 22 (ssh) is open to the world, but that's it. You need to allow traffic to port 4444 of that instance. That's done through security groups. If you go to the AWS console, you can find the security group associated with your instance under the Description tab.

Comment: Got it, let me try and then I update here.

Answer (score 0):

Please allow access to the port 4444 in the security rules for that EC2 instance. Basically what @detroyejr said above.

Comment: I already figured when we found that curl command didn't give any error. I need to do the porting so that I can it's public IP via the browser.